# HTML password Input field Autocomplete "off" is not working

Tags: angular

I tried below solution to off Autocomplete but still autocomplete is showing for password field

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"> 

<input  [(ngModel)]="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" class="password-input" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" autocomplete="off" type="password" required>
```

Comment: Probably that is not an issue of autocomplete, I suspect that is a saved password autofill, Open [chrome settings](chrome://settings/passwords) and remove the saved password.

Comment: actually want to solve this issue in code. need to remove autocomplete from password field

Comment: put input field for email like  <input placeholder="email" type="text" class="email-input password-fill"> and set zindex to -1. solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try `autocomplete="new-password"` instead of `autocomplete="off"` in your input tag.

Comment: already tried it, it is not working in chrome